# How to write in a Xml using derived classes?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

maybe the title is not the best description.

My situation is, depending on a interface I want to write one of its properties which is object. Please watch the following example:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    // anothers properties...
    object Value { get; }
}
```

And I have three implementations of it here, check that Value can be is hidden the true datatype.

```
public class FooA : IFoo
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    object IFoo.Value { get { return Value; } }
}

public class FooB : IFoo
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    object IFoo.Value { get { return Value; } }
}

public class FooC : IFoo
{
    public List<double> Value { get; set; }
    object IFoo.Value { get { return Value; } }
}
```

In my scenario was very important not using generics. So with this implementation I need to write in a Xml just the property Value.

For example:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<IFoo> fooList = new List<IFoo>()
        {
            new FooA() { Value = "String" },
            new FooB() { Value = 2 },
            new FooC() { Value = new List<double>() {2, 3.4 } } 
        };

        // Write in a Xml the elements of this list with the property Value (and the problem is the datartype,
        // strings, ints, lists, etc)
        // ...
    }
```

I was thinking using XmlSerialization, but I don't want to store all the properties of the object, just Value property.

I need a way to write the property Value (not to store all the properties of that interface) and a Way to know which implementation of IFoo I'm using.

UPDATE: I wanna have an XML file like this.

```
<Foos>
    <Foo xsi:Type="FooA" Value="String" />
    <Foo xsi:Type="FooB" Value="2" />
    <Foo xsi:Type="FooC" >
        <Value>
            <List xsi:Type="Double">
                <Element>2</Element>
                <Element>3.4</Element>
            </List>
        </Value>
    </Foo
</Foos>
```

This is just an idea. The idea is to store just a property of IFoo and the capability to get the concrete object with the value.

UPDATE:

Thanks to Raj Nagalingam to help me with the idea. This is what I've accomplished.

```
public interface IFoo
{
    object Value { get; }
}

public abstract class Foo<T> : IFoo, IXmlSerializable
{
    [XmlElement]
    public T Value { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    object IFoo.Value { get { return Value; } }

    XmlSchema IXmlSerializable.GetSchema() { return null; }
    void IXmlSerializable.ReadXml(XmlReader reader) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    void IXmlSerializable.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        XmlSerializer serial = new XmlSerializer(Value.GetType());
        serial.Serialize(writer, Value);
    }
}

public class FooA : Foo<string> { }
public class FooB : Foo<int> { }
public class FooC : Foo<List<Double>> { }
public class FooContainer : List<IFoo>, IXmlSerializable
{
    public XmlSchema GetSchema() { return null; }
    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader) { throw new NotImplementedException(); } 
    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        ForEach(x => 
            {
                XmlSerializer serial = new XmlSerializer(x.GetType());
                serial.Serialize(writer, x);
            });
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FooContainer fooList = new FooContainer()
        {
            new FooA() { Value = "String" },
            new FooB() { Value = 2 },
            new FooC() { Value = new List<double>() {2, 3.4 } } 
        };

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(fooList.GetType(),
            new Type[] { typeof(FooA), typeof(FooB), typeof(FooC) });
        System.IO.TextWriter textWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\temp\demo.xml");
        serializer.Serialize(textWriter, fooList);
        textWriter.Close();
    }
}
```

And it works, but I guess it's impossible to recover the list with the concrete classes, Using the standard serialization I see that it's written using xsi, and this time I can't see them. How can I recover my objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one of the way of implementing it, please take a look and also pls extend/refactor it based on your needs. I hope it helps.

```
public interface IFoo : IXmlSerializable
{
    // anothers properties...
    object Value { get; }
}

[XmlRoot("Foo")]
public class FooA : IFoo
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    object IFoo.Value { get { return Value; } }

    #region IXmlSerializable Members

    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("Foo");

        writer.WriteStartAttribute("Type", "http://example.com/2007/ns1");
        writer.WriteString(GetType().Name);
        writer.WriteEndAttribute();

        writer.WriteStartAttribute("Value");
        writer.WriteString(Value.ToString());
        writer.WriteEndAttribute();

        writer.WriteEndElement();

    }

    #endregion
}

[XmlRoot("Foo")]
public class FooB : IFoo
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    object IFoo.Value { get { return Value; } }

    #region IXmlSerializable Members

    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("Foo");

        writer.WriteStartAttribute("Type", "http://example.com/2007/ns1");
        writer.WriteString(GetType().Name);
        writer.WriteEndAttribute();

        writer.WriteStartAttribute("Value");
        writer.WriteString(Value.ToString());
        writer.WriteEndAttribute();

        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }

    #endregion
}

[XmlRoot("Foo")]
public class FooC : IFoo
{
    public List<double> Value { get; set; }
    object IFoo.Value { get { return Value; } }

    #region IXmlSerializable Members

    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("Foo");

        writer.WriteStartAttribute("Type", "http://example.com/2007/ns1");
        writer.WriteString(GetType().Name);
        writer.WriteEndAttribute();

        writer.WriteStartElement("Value");

        if (Value != null)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("List");

            writer.WriteStartAttribute("Type", "http://example.com/2007/ns1");
            writer.WriteString(typeof(double).Name);
            writer.WriteEndAttribute();

            foreach (double value in Value)
            {
                writer.WriteElementString("Element", value.ToString());
            }

            writer.WriteEndElement();

        }

        writer.WriteEndElement();

        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }

    #endregion
}

[XmlRoot("Foos")]
public class ListCotainer : List<IFoo>, IXmlSerializable
{
    #region IXmlSerializable Members

    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", null, "http://example.com/2007/ns1");
        foreach (IFoo foo in this)
        {
            foo.WriteXml(writer);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlWriterSettings _xws = new XmlWriterSettings();
        _xws.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
        _xws.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Auto;
        _xws.Indent = true;

        ListCotainer container = new ListCotainer()
        {
                new FooA() { Value = "String" },
                new FooB() { Value = 2 },
                new FooC() { Value = new List<double>() {2, 3.4 } } 
        };

        StringBuilder xmlString = new StringBuilder();
        using (XmlWriter xtw = XmlTextWriter.Create(xmlString, _xws))
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(container.GetType());
            serializer.Serialize(xtw, container);

            xtw.Flush();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(xmlString.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems it's okay with the solution. I'm planning to create hundred of modules like Foo, so many of them can contain a repeated data type. Do you think is the only way to do this? Because each modulo I implement should have IXmlSerialization

Comment: Yes, this is the only way to customize your XML serialization of your classes the way you need it. If don't care about the XML output, you can might as well use standard serialization which .NET provides.

Comment: do you think is possible use the standard serialization for example [XmlElement] in the Value property. I'm getting problems because I was trying to serialize an interface

Comment: It is not possible to use standard serialization for serializing interfaces. Either you will have to convert to abstract class or use custom serialization as I posted code before.